# How do I properly integrate my smart contract?

Tags: javascript, json, solidity

I've been struggling with smart contracts for a few weeks now and im seriously making progress but i'm stuck at this point...

```
class App extends Component {
  
    async componentWillMount() {
      await this.loadWeb3()
      await this.loadBlockchainData()
    }
      async loadBlockchainData() {
      const web3 = window.web3
  
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
      this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })
  
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId() 

      
    const Musketeer = Musketeer.networks[networkId]
    if(Musketeer) {
      const Musketeer = new web3.eth.Contract(Musketeer.abi, Musketeer.address)

/// I DONT NEED THIS PART ANYMORE I"LL SKIP DISPLAYING THE BALANCE ///
    
this.setState({ Musketeer })
      let MusketeerBalance = await Musketeer.methods.balanceOf(this.state.account).call()
      this.setState({ MusketeerBalance: MusketeerBalance.toString() })

//////////////////////////////////

    } else {
      window.alert('Musketeer contract not deployed to detected network.')
    }
  
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }
  
    async loadWeb3() {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
        await window.ethereum.enable()
      }
      else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
      }
      else {
        window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
      }
    }
```

I'm trying here to put the contract musketeer in the App.js but I don't fully understand what I have to do to integrate this. If someone could explain this to me in Neanderthal language I would be grateful for the rest of my life.. I simply don't get it at this point.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The steps to connect to this contract from your React App.js would be as follows:

Prerequisite: contract is deployed and you have it's address. If you're using truffle, `truffle develop` then `truffle migrate --reset` should deploy your contract locally. See [this truffle blog](https://www.trufflesuite.com/blog/an-easier-way-to-deploy-your-smart-contracts).

1. Load web3, if the user has a wallet
2. (Optionally) put the web3 object and the accounts object from `web3.eth.getAccounts()` in your state
3. Create the contract instance with the address from deployment. You can also deploy the contract dynamically from the app, but this is more complicated.
4. Add the contract to your state
5. Call methods on the contract

Check out this [github repo](https://github.com/truffle-box/react-box/blob/master/client/src/App.js) and add what you need.

Comment: Thanks alot dude, this is just what I needed! Thank you for your time, I can swim on my own from here !